# Accolade to take objects together in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, brackets

Is there a way to draw an accolade (`{`-symbol) that groups things together in TikZ? I want the accolade to group let's say three rectangles. That means the top of the upper reactangle must be the top of the accolade, and the bottom of the lower triangle the bottom of the accolade. Of course I can draw an accolade using a node, but I haven't found a way yet to make sure the size meets this constraint. Is there a solution or a workaround for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A solution more simple ( for me ) and with the possibility of scaling. I add the solution with Andrew's idea The code is very clear but we can not make a scale and perhaps there is a better solution to create more space vertically. The brace is more pretty with the matrix's delimiter.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace}][scale=2] 
   \node [draw] (A) {A}; 
   \node [draw,yshift=1cm] (B) at (A) {B};
   \node [draw,yshift=1cm] (C) at (B) {C};
   \node [fit=(A) (B) (C)] (fit) {};              
  \draw [decorate,line width=1pt] (fit.south west) -- (fit.north west);
\end{tikzpicture} 
 \hspace*{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] 
\matrix [matrix of nodes,left delimiter=\{,nodes={draw}] {
A  \\[12pt] B \\[12pt] C \\
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative is to use the `matrix` library and put `left delimiter=\{` (I may be misremembering the syntax) on the "fitted" node.

Comment: I added your idea but you don't need to use  the "fitted" node. The brace is more pretty but we can't scale the picture. It's  not a big problem; this feature depends of the use of the picture

Comment: The accolade needs to span a length of approx. 45 cm. This makes the accolade look like a normal line (only if you look very close you see it's an accolade), are there any parameters to the brace? (I mean the first option)?

Comment: I've found it myself: decoration={brace,amplitude=10} did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `fit` TikZ library to create a rectangular node which encompasses the nodes, e.g. your three rectangles. Then you can use the node anchors to draw your `{` either using a scaled `{` character (`\resizebox{!}{<height of fit>}{\{}`) or using drawing commands. Two bezier curves should do it.

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [draw] (A) {A};
   \node [draw,below of=A] (B) {B};
   \node [draw,below of=B] (C) {C};
   \node [fit=(A) (B) (C)] (fit) {};
   \path let \p1=(fit.north west), \p2 = (fit.south east) in
       node [left of=fit] {%
       \pgfmathsetmacro\heightoffit{.8*(\y1-\y2)}%
       \resizebox{!}{\heightoffit pt}{\{}%
     };%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `brace` decoration.

Comment: @Caramdir: Ah, I didn't know about that. Thanks.

Comment: I think the line width of the brace is ... very great ! :)

Comment: @Altermundus: I noticed :-) Could be fixed by some horizontal-only down-scaling. But your solution seems to be preferable.

Comment: Andrew's idea is very fine too !